# Copying a column from one table to another

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, sql-update

I have `photos` table onto which I'm trying to insert a new column from another table by filtering data with a `WHERE` clause. Here is the query I'm trying to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE photos ADD COLUMN new_count BIGINT;

INSERT INTO photos (new_count)
SELECT c.cnt
FROM c
WHERE  
    c.created = photos.created;
```

But in the result I am getting an error:

```
Error : ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "photos"
LINE 5:  c.created = photos.created
```

How can avoid the error and copy the column?
I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: Use UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: How granular is your created time?  Is it possible for multiple photos to have been created at the same millisecond?  You want to be careful that you only update the right rows.  You don't have an id column to join on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join in the referenced table `c` with a `FROM` clause.

```
UPDATE photos p
SET    new_count = c.cnt
FROM   c
WHERE  c.created = p.created
AND    c.cnt IS NOT NULL;  -- optional, depends on additional circumstances
```

[Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

Correlated subqueries (like [demonstrated by @Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28150021/939860)) are generally slower, and they also have a **side effect** that's typically undesirable:
If no matching row is found in `c`, the `UPDATE` proceeds regardless and `new_count` is set to NULL. This happens to be *not wrong* in this particular case (since the column is NULL by definition of the case). It's still pointless extra cost. Often, the effect is actively harmful, though.

The added condition `AND c.cnt IS NOT NULL` further avoids empty updates if the new value is no different from the old. Useless if `c.cnt` cannot be NULL. It's the simplified form of the generic check: `AND c.cnt IS DISTINCT FROM p.new_count`. Details (last paragraph):

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert` to add rows to a table, and `update` to change existing rows.  Here's an example of how to update a column in `photos` based on a link to the `c` table:

```
update photos p
set    new_count = 
       (
       select  cnt
       from    c
       where   c.created = p.created
       )
```